# copy list of objects into another list of objects

Tags: c#

I have a question here. Lets say I have these two classes

```
class Person
{
    int person_id;
    string name;
    Address address;
}

class Address
{
    int address_id;
    string street;
}
```

and I have list of Person data in `List<Person> people = new List<Person>();`.

Now I want to copy all of the `address` in `people` to a new address list `List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do a [projection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546168.aspx) which means take the objects and transform them into another form:

```
List<Address> addresses = people.Select(p => p.Address).ToList();
```

Comment: it seems what i'm looking for. i'll have a try. ta

Answer (score 0):

(From p in people select p.Address).ToList()
Is that it?

Comment: i'm sorry but i dont really understand with that

Comment: Ah It is same like answer above, but using linq query, for me it's self explaining